# Does Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity Support OAuth 2.0 login?

Tags: oauth, openid

I came across [this page](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID?#adjust-uri) from Google about Migrating to OAuth 2.0 login (OpenID Connect)

My current project has already used the Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth library to implement the external login feature using Google account. But I am not sure whether this library still supports OAuth 2.0 login when the OpenID 2.0 is eventually shut down in the near future. Does someone have an confirmed answer about it? Thanks.